# What is the right way to get Page object via Sling Model annotation

Tags: aem, sling, sightly, htl

I have a property with the path to required page in a content file

```
...
<some_block
    ...
    sling:resourceType="some_path_to_some_component"
    somePage="some_path_to_page"
    .../>
...
```

suitable HTL component **some-component.html**

```
<div data-sly-use.some_model="org.example.SomeModel">
    ...    
</div>
```

and model class **SomeModel.java**

```
package org.example;
...
import com.day.cq.wcm.api.Page;
...

@Model(adaptables = { SlingHttpServletRequest.class, Resource.class },
    defaultInjectionStrategy = DefaultInjectionStrategy.REQUIRED)
public class RelatedContentBlock {

    @ValueMapValue
    private Page somePage;

    ...
}
```

I easily can get the required Page object using [@Inject](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Inject.html) and [@Via](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling7/org/apache/sling/models/annotations/Via.html) annotations, but why can't I grab it with the [@ValueMapValue](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling8/org/apache/sling/models/annotations/injectorspecific/ValueMapValue.html) annotation? I tried to use all the possible variants including *via* attribute and so on. And yes, I can get it from the *[pageManager](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/htl/docs/global-objects.html)*, but what's wrong with [@ValueMapValue](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling8/org/apache/sling/models/annotations/injectorspecific/ValueMapValue.html)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you so eager to use the `@ValueMapValue` annotation if you already know how to inject a `Page` with other annotations?

Comment: @Jens just to get the reason why it doesn't work, besides it looked more elegant for me to use `@ValueMapValue`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation that you linked of the `@ValueMapValue` annotation has the answer you are looking for:

> Annotation to be used on either methods, fields or constructor parameter to let Sling Models inject a value from the ValueMap of the current resource.

The important part is:

> inject a value from the ValueMap

A `Page` is not a `ValueMap`. Therefore, this annotation can not be used to inject a page.

This annotation is mainly used to inject *page properties*. Because page properties (or resource properties for that matter) are stored in a `ValueMap`. That is why you can use the `@ValueMapValue` annotation to inject the `jcr:title` of a page:

```
@ValueMapValue(name = "jcr:title")
private String title;
```

This is equivalent to (pseudo code):

```
final ValueMap pageProperites = Page.getProperties();
final String title = pageProperties.get("jcr:title", "" /* default */);
```